# What is the correct way to approach abstract class solution with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I know abstract classes are not a feature in Ruby, and surely there is a philosophic reason behind that, but I would like to know if there is way to approach problems that typically are resolved using abstract classes in other languages like C++ and Java.

For example:
I need three classes `Triangle`, `Square`, and `Circle`. Because these are all geometric figures, I was thinking in coding an abstract class called `AbstractFigure` with an abstract method `get_area`, which would be implemented by the concrete classes `Triangle`, `Square`, and `Circle`.

How can I do this following Ruby philosophy?

Comment: Just create a base class and don't instantiate it. Looks good enough to me. :)

Comment: Remember Ruby is dynamically typed, so you don’t even need a base class – just three classes that all have `get_area` method.

Answer (score 9):

You're right that it doesn't exist as a well defined concept in ruby, unlike other languages like Java where it's used heavily.

But you're also right that there's plenty of situations that warrant it.

Here's how I've gone about it, with your example -

```
class AbstractShape
  attr_accessor :edges

  def initialize
    # ...
  end

  def get_area
    raise NoMethodError("Override this implementation")
  end
end


class Square < AbstractShape
   def initialize
     # square-specific stuff
     super
   end

   def get_area
     self.edges * foo * bar
   end
end
```

The key is to define all the available methods at the top level for readability and consistency, but make sure they raise an error if used.

If there is a method that you are absolutely sure will be used consistently the same way across all shapes, then define it in `AbstractShape`

The `attr_accessor` will also inherit, so you'll have `@edges` available on a per instance basis for each shape. But you can still have methods within the `AbstractShape` class that reference `@edges`, because they'll just use the correct local instance variable.

Comment: Perhaps note a)`AbstractShape` can have mix of methods, some of which are inherited and others, as above, which force the same method to be defined in a subclass; and b) to prevent `AbstractShape` from being instantiated one could give it the method `def initialize; raise "Cannot instantiate class AbstractShape" if self.class ==  AbstractShape; ... ;end`.

Answer (score 7):

Define a normal class `AbstractFigure` with a method `get_area` that just raises `NotImplementedError`. Then each derived class overrides the `get_area` method with it's own implementation.

```
class AbstractFigure
    def get_area
        raise NotImplementedError.new( 'appropriate error message' )
    end
end

class Square < AbstractFigure
    def get_area
        # implementation here
    end
end
```